# error:"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid message options" in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to call registerValidation function that is defined in file validation.js from auth.js, but error appears that

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid message options

Can anyone tell me why and how to correct it?

auth.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../model/User")
const  {registerValidation} = require("./validation")


router.post('/register', async(req, res)=>{

    //Lets validate the data
//error appears here
    const {error} = registerValidation(req.body);
    if(error){
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)
    }
    const user = new User({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password
    });
    try{
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.send(savedUser); 
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err)
    }
})




module.exports = router;
```

validation.js

```
//VALIDATION
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi")


const registerValidation = (data) => { 
    const schema = Joi.object({
        name:Joi.string().min(6).required(),
        email:Joi.string().min(6).required().email(),
        password:Joi.string().min(6).required()
    });
    return schema.validate(data, schema)
}


const loginValidation = data =>{
    const schema = Joi.object({
        email:Joi.string().min(6).required().email(),
        password:Joi.string().min(6).required()
    });
    return schema.validate(data, schema)
}


module.exports =  {registerValidation, loginValidation};
```

Comment: I don't believe your issue is related to your validation functions, but try to put everything inside `try/catch` and see what the exact error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the registerValidation and loginValidation function should be like  given below

```
   const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

const registerValidation = (data) => {
     console.log("body ", data)
    const schema = Joi.object({

        name:Joi.string().min(6).required(),
        email:Joi.string().min(6).required().email(),
        password:Joi.string().min(6).required()
    });
    
    return  schema.validate(data)  //change here
}

const loginValidation = data =>{
    const schema = Joi.object({
        email:Joi.string().min(6).required().email(),
        password:Joi.string().min(6).required()
    });
    return schema.validate(data)     //change here
}


module.exports =  {registerValidation, loginValidation};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your functions inside an object and then export that object, like in the following example:

```js
const registerValidation = (data) => {...}
const loginValidation = (data) => {...}

module.exports = {
  registerValidation,
  loginValidation
}
```

Alternatively, since `module.exports` is an object itself, you could do something like the following:

```js
const registerValidation = (data) => {...}
const loginValidation = (data) => {...}

module.exports.registerValidation = registerValidation;
module.exports.loginValidation = loginValidation;
```

Comment: Error changes to -> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid message options

Comment: You have a different issue that's unrelated to exporting those functions.